# PHP Getting data from user and searching into multiple Columns

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I have a database table named
group(group_name, admin_name);

I've designed a form for searching the group (A Simple TextBox and a Search Button)

Now the query is, whatever the user enters into the TextBox, it should search the string into the entire table and return the values (i.e. Group Name and Admin Name)

I can do this for only a single column
$text = // the String entered by User;

```
SELECT * FROM `group` WHERE `group_name` LIKE '%$text%'; (For group_name column)
SELECT * FROM `group` WHERE `admin_name` LIKE '%$text%'; (For admin_name column)
```

I want to do it for both....
I use this for both columns

`SELECT * FROM` `group` `WHERE` `group_name` `LIKE '%$text%' or` `admin_name` `LIKE '%$text%';`

Here I'm getting Duplicate values
I want to make it like a Search Engine
Please Help

Comment: Try combining both in `()` `(group_name LIKE '%$text%' or admin_name LIKE '%$text%')`

Comment: to who you thanks too brother..?

Comment: all those Answered and also for u too
I cant answer my own question coz my level is very low in stackoverflow
Otherwise I would hav posted in general

Comment: see you reputation enhanced 5 more...cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try-

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `group` WHERE `group_name` LIKE '%$text%' or `admin_name` LIKE '%$text%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use distinct and group  them in where

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM group
WHERE (group_name LIKE '%$text%'
    or admin_name LIKE '%$text%');
```